# When does php prepare to send headers?

Tags: php, execution, output-buffering, response-headers, die

I wish to review and change headers before they are sent & also be able to stop any content from being send if headers are not to my liking or other conditions are not met.

When I set a function for header_register_callback, the headers can be adjusted perfectly. However, when using a die() statement in the callback, it does not prevent the triggering statement from being outputted. This appears only to be an issue in php 8.0.0 - 8.0.10

Looking at the description of the header register callback:
"The callback is executed just after PHP prepares all headers to be sent, and **before any other output is sent**, creating a window to manipulate the outgoing headers before being sent."

Why does the below example still output:

> In php 8.0.0 - 8.0.10, a die statement does prevent the trigger from
> being outputted: Trigger.

as opposed to:

> In php 8.0.0 - 8.0.10, a die statement does prevent the trigger from
> being outputted:

```
<?php
    ob_start(); // make sure ob_level is set to 1

    function callback()
    {
        echo "In php 8.0.0 - 8.0.10, a die statement does prevent the trigger from being outputted: ";
        die();
    }
    header_register_callback("callback");

    ob_end_clean();
    echo "Trigger.";
    echo "Execution died before this echo statement.";
```

I've made a bug report about this as well on: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81431
Example snippet: https://3v4l.org/0NITj

Comment: You didn't pass `$test` to the function...

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the mention. I edited the question. The reason to use the test, is to see if the output check is called before or after. If I set echo duck after the setting test to true, the output check will be ommitted.

Comment: [This seems to only happen in PHP 8](https://3v4l.org/5A8tf). PHP 7 and earlier exhibit the expected behaviour.

Comment: Based on [this](https://3v4l.org/1evJ9) I would guess that PHP 8 applies an "optimisation" of adding the first "duck" to the output buffer right away, before calling the header callback. Maybe submit a bug report?

Comment: @Siguza Thank you for the feedback. I was unaware that in previous versions this seemed to be working differently. I've made a bug report, but am still unsure whether it is intended behaviour or not, due to their JIT approach in 8.0.0 onwards. If so, I'd still find it strange behaviour and the documentation is not very understandable to me.